# Can I program an application within itself - Xcode/iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using xcode 5 for iOS 7 and I want to know if it is possible to write code within an application that the application will then add to its own code and run immediately. One idea I had was that perhaps if statements might be able to use a string as a test, but I'm not sure how. for example, if the user wrote "x>2", then the program might take string = "x>2" and run:

```
if(string){
    //then the desired response here
}
```

I am aware I may be being too vague. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

No, that's not possible, the code has to be compiled before it can run, you cannot add lines to it while is running.

Just imagine how insecure the app would be if this was possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have your app run javascript.  I have successfully done this in the past with [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`
, but you might also checkout the [JavaScriptCore Framework](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/WebKit_JavaScriptCore_Ref).

I don't know if this would suit your needs.

Comment: That's quite helpful and along the right lines. I'll certainly check it out. another solution I'm now considering is defining the relationships as code and leaving the variables as replaceable parts - mathematical operators, string isEqualTo string, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Apple changed the terms of the developer program agreement late in 2010 to allow interpreters (so long as they don't download code), so there's nothing stopping you from running an interpreted language, such as Python or Lua or, indeed, your own language within an app.